# How to display rendered field dynamically

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax

It may seem that my question is out of topic, yet if you read whole text, you'll find that not.

I've custom content-type

[image]

When I display content of that type, initially there isn't field_zdjecie_1. I want to dynamically display that field, e.g. after pressing the button. How can I do it?

Comment: You want to add a new field to the content type fields programmatically?

Comment: No. I want to display field dynamically, e.g. after press the button. If my field was a string, I would know what should I do using json. But, my field-type is a file, and I don't know what can I do. Clearly, after press the button I want to display file-typed field which wasn't displayed before.